# Synchronize in Flux doOnEach

Tags: java, project-reactor

Let's look at this example:

```
class ReactiveApp {

    static volatile int count = 0;
    static final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    static final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(2);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Flux.range(0, 100_000)
                .parallel()
                .runOn(Schedulers.single())
                .doOnEach(i -> {
                    lock.lock();
                    count++;
                    lock.unlock();
                })
                .doOnComplete(() -> latch.countDown())
                .subscribe();

        Flux.range(0, 100_000)
                .parallel()
                .runOn(Schedulers.single())
                .doOnEach(i -> {
                    lock.lock();
                    count++;
                    lock.unlock();
                })
                .doOnComplete(() -> latch.countDown())
                .subscribe();

        latch.await();

        System.out.println(count);

    }
}
```

The above code increments `count` on each element in a synchronous way. I expect `System.out.println(count);` to print `200000`. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: You didn't share what is your actual result. I'm assuming it's 200002. It's because doOnEach is triggered on complete events as well. Try doOnNext instead.

Comment: @MartinTarjányi Actually it was far below 10K. That's why I was a bit confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't actually specify the issue in the question I'm going to assume the number is significantly smaller than you were expecting.

This is due to you using onComplete on a parallelFlux.

> Run the specified runnable when a 'rail' completes.

Note that it says when a 'rail' completes, not when all rails have completed.

This means that your latch is counting down the instant one 'rail' completes.

With smaller numbers you would probably see it is the total / num cpu cores (or number of rails if set explicitly)

With larger numbers it will likely be more random due to multiple rails running at slightly different rates.

Anyway one solution is to merge the parallelFlux back together before calling onComplete using `sequential()`, so only when all rails have completed is the runnable called.

```
    Flux.range(0, 100_000)
            .parallel()
            .runOn(Schedulers.single())
            .doOnNext(i -> {
                lock.lock();
                count.incrementAndGet();
                lock.unlock();
            })
            .sequential()
            .doOnComplete(latch::countDown)
            .subscribe();
```

Also some other notes on the above code

`doOnNext` is used to prevent on complete events also incrementing count.
`count` I have changed to an AtomicInteger and call `incrementAndGet()`, to provide better thread safety

Comment: Perfect! Let me see if I got this right. `doOnNext` is having its own dedicated thread(s) for parallel work and then they are merged back when `sequential` is invoked. After invoking `sequential`, if I again invoke `doOnNext` then the work will be performed on a single thread. Right?

Comment: @Trey Almost, it actually doesn't have anything to do with threads, each `rail` is effectively a different Flux/Stream that is allocated a portion of the elements (total/number of rails).  As such, onComplete, onNext, ect only operates on that `rail`s own elements. `Sequential()` merges these all back into a single Flux/Stream.